# Maintaining Multiple Different Alignments Between Lines of Equations

Tags: equations, align

My code is as follows:

```
\documentclass[fleqn, 12pt]{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {./images/} }
\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}%
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}%
\begin{document}
\raggedright

\begin{align}
&\sum\limits_{i = 1}^n X_i[Y_i - (\bar{Y} - \hat{\beta_1}\bar{X}) - \hat{\beta_1} X_i] = 0 \nonumber \\
&\rightarrow \sum\limits_{i = 1}^n X_iY_i - \sum\limits_{i = 1}^n X_i\bar{Y} + \sum\limits_{i = 1}^n X_i\hat{\beta_1}\bar{X} - \sum\limits_{i = 1}^n \hat{\beta_1} X_i^2 = 0 \nonumber \\
&\rightarrow \sum\limits_{i = 1}^n X_i(Y_i - \bar{Y}) + \sum\limits_{i = 1}^n X_i(\hat{\beta_1}\bar{X} - \hat{\beta_1} X_i) = 0 \nonumber \\
&\rightarrow \sum\limits_{i = 1}^n X_i(Y_i - \bar{Y}) = -\sum\limits_{i = 1}^n X_i(\hat{\beta_1}\bar{X} - \hat{\beta_1} X_i) \nonumber \\
&= \sum\limits_{i = 1}^n X_i(\hat{\beta_1} X_i - \hat{\beta_1}\bar{X}) \nonumber \\
&= \hat{\beta_1}\sum\limits_{i = 1}^n X_i( X_i - \bar{X}) \nonumber \\
&\rightarrow \hat{\beta_1} = \dfrac{\sum\limits_{i = 1}^n X_i(Y_i - \bar{Y})}{\sum\limits_{i = 1}^n X_i( X_i - \bar{X})} \nonumber
\end{align} 

\end{document}
```

Notice that, at some point, my lines switch from beginning with \rightarrow to just =, since I don't want to superfluously repeat \rightarrow. But then, for the last line, it once again becomes necessary to have \rightarrow. I want to have the \rightarrows align with each other and the = in the two lines

```
&= \sum\limits_{i = 1}^n X_i(\hat{\beta_1} X_i - \hat{\beta_1}\bar{X}) \nonumber \\
&= \hat{\beta_1}\sum\limits_{i = 1}^n X_i( X_i - \bar{X}) \nonumber \\
```

to align with the = in the line before them

```
&\rightarrow \sum\limits_{i = 1}^n X_i(Y_i - \bar{Y}) (ALIGNED HERE)= -\sum\limits_{i = 1}^n X_i(\hat{\beta_1}\bar{X} - \hat{\beta_1} X_i) \nonumber \\
```

But I want the last line

```
&\rightarrow \hat{\beta_1} = \dfrac{\sum\limits_{i = 1}^n X_i(Y_i - \bar{Y})}{\sum\limits_{i = 1}^n X_i( X_i - \bar{X})} \nonumber
\end{align}
```

To align with all of the other lines that start with \rightarrow

```
&\rightarrow \sum\limits_{i = 1}^n X_iY_i - \sum\limits_{i = 1}^n X_i\bar{Y} + \sum\limits_{i = 1}^n X_i\hat{\beta_1}\bar{X} - \sum\limits_{i = 1}^n \hat{\beta_1} X_i^2 = 0 \nonumber \\
&\rightarrow \sum\limits_{i = 1}^n X_i(Y_i - \bar{Y}) + \sum\limits_{i = 1}^n X_i(\hat{\beta_1}\bar{X} - \hat{\beta_1} X_i) = 0 \nonumber \\
&\rightarrow \sum\limits_{i = 1}^n X_i(Y_i - \bar{Y}) = -\sum\limits_{i = 1}^n X_i(\hat{\beta_1}\bar{X} - \hat{\beta_1} X_i) \nonumber \\
```

So we would essentially be maintaining two different alignments.

I'm not sure if there's some ability to maintain additional alignment symbols to `&` for this purpose? It seems like this would be a simple solution.

I would greatly appreciate it if people could please take the time to clarify this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an `aligned` environments for the `=` alignment. I propose a second variant which looks nicer in my opinion.

B.t.w., needless to repeat `\nonumber` on every line of the environment: just use an `align*` environment instead. Also, writing \sum`\limits` is not required in display style: this is the default. It is only required for the final `\sums` in the fraction (albeit I think it looks better with the default `\nolimits`). Also  you don't have to load `amsfonts` since you load `amssymb` which does it for you.

```
\documentclass[fleqn, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools, amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {./images/} }
\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}%
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}%

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
&\sum_{i = 1}^n X_i[Y_i - (\bar{Y} - \hat{\beta_1}\bar{X}) - \hat{\beta_1} X_i] = 0 \\
&\rightarrow \sum_{i = 1}^n X_iY_i - \sum_{i = 1}^n X_i\bar{Y} + \sum_{i = 1}^n X_i\hat{\beta_1}\bar{X} - \sum_{i = 1}^n \hat{\beta_1} X_i^2 = 0 \\
&\rightarrow \sum_{i = 1}^n X_i(Y_i - \bar{Y}) + \sum_{i = 1}^n X_i(\hat{\beta_1}\bar{X} - \hat{\beta_1} X_i) = 0 \\
&\rightarrow \sum_{i = 1}^n X_i(Y_i - \bar{Y})
\begin{aligned}[t] & = -\sum_{i = 1}^n X_i(\hat{\beta_1}\bar{X} - \hat{\beta_1} X_i) \\
&= \sum_{i = 1}^n X_i(\hat{\beta_1} X_i - \hat{\beta_1}\bar{X}) \\
&= \hat{\beta_1}\sum_{i = 1}^n X_i( X_i - \bar{X})
\end{aligned} \\
&\rightarrow \hat{\beta_1} = \dfrac{\sum\limits_{i = 1}^n X_i(Y_i - \bar{Y})}{\sum\limits_{i = 1}^n X_i( X_i - \bar{X})}
\end{align*}
\raggedright

\begin{align*}
&\sum_{i = 1}^n X_i[Y_i - (\bar{Y} - \hat{\beta_1}\bar{X}) - \hat{\beta_1} X_i] = 0 \\
&\rightarrow \sum_{i = 1}^n X_iY_i - \sum_{i = 1}^n X_i\bar{Y} + \sum_{i = 1}^n X_i\hat{\beta_1}\bar{X} - \sum_{i = 1}^n \hat{\beta_1} X_i^2 = 0 \\
&\rightarrow \sum_{i = 1}^n X_i(Y_i - \bar{Y}) + \sum_{i = 1}^n X_i(\hat{\beta_1}\bar{X} - \hat{\beta_1} X_i) = 0 \\
&\rightarrow \sum_{i = 1}^n X_i(Y_i - \bar{Y})
\begin{aligned}[t] & = -\sum_{i = 1}^n X_i(\hat{\beta_1}\bar{X} - \hat{\beta_1} X_i) = \sum_{i = 1}^n X_i(\hat{\beta_1} X_i - \hat{\beta_1}\bar{X})\\
& = \hat{\beta_1}\sum_{i = 1}^n X_i( X_i - \bar{X})
\end{aligned} \\
&\rightarrow \hat{\beta_1} = \dfrac{\sum\limits_{i = 1}^n X_i(Y_i - \bar{Y})}{\sum\limits_{i = 1}^n X_i( X_i - \bar{X})}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]